# How can I use Ansible of a serial connection instead of SSH?

Tags: ansible, serial-port, uart

I have a bunch of Raspberry Pi devices that I only configure over the serial console.  I am hoping to configure Ansible to update them for me.

I can't find any obvious way to do it (on this list for example: [Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/plugins.html))

Do I need to write my own connector? Or is there an obvious way to use Ansible of a serial console that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

> *Do I need to write my own connector*

Right, currently, there is no serial connection possible out-of-box. You will need a connector like [Ansible Serial Unix](https://gitlab.com/Ckarles/ansible-serial-unix) and enhance em for your needs (if necessary).