# How to connect using console(serial port) between Ansible to Cisco?

Tags: ansible, console, cisco

I'm using Ansible for automation network devices.

After cisco switch factory reset, I don't know that how to connect cisco console port instead of ssh.

I want to know way only serial(console port) connection that ansible connects to brand new cisco devices without setting IP for ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no serial connection possible out-of-box. You will need a connector like [Ansible Serial Unix](https://gitlab.com/Ckarles/ansible-serial-unix) and enhance em for your needs (if necessary). Or [develop a plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html) by your own.

**Further Q&A**

- [How can I use Ansible of a serial connection instead of SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62977303/)
- [User Guide - Connection plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html)
- [Dev Guide - Connection plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#connection-plugins)